# Rails: update the number of votes 'votes_count' with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a pretty simple upvote system in my rails app. I would like to update the votes_count through an ajax request everytime someone upvote a Pin. But I can't figure out what I am missing.

**app/controllers/pin_controller.rb**

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: { count: @pin.votes_count } }
 end
end
```

**app/views/pins/index.html.erb**

```
<span class='pin-<%=pin.id%>'>
  <%= link_to upvote_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true do %>         
      <% if pin.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).empty? %>
         <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <%= pin.votes.count %>
</span>
```

***app/views/pins/upvote.js.erb**

```
$("pin-<%=pin.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript pin.votes.count %>');
```

Any ideas what I am missing to get it work ?

*update:*
**The error from the console:**

send jquery.js?body=1:9667jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9212$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:81$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:157(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:307jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4625elemData.handle

**server log error:**

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for 3:Fixnum):
    1: $(".pin-<%=@pin.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript @pin.votes.count %>');
  app/views/pins/upvote.js.erb:1:in`_app_views_pins_upvote_js_erb___4096032730150237755_70323561115600'
  app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:53:in `upvote'

SOLUTION:

**modified this line to in upvote.js.erb:**

$(".pin-<%=@pin.id%>").html('<%= @pin.votes.count %>');

Answer (score 1):

Use "format.js", not "format.json".

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of errors:

**app/controllers/pin_controller.rb**

```
def upvote
  @pin = Pin.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @pin.votes.create(user_id: current_user.id)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js # no need to pass a variable here
 end
end
```

**app/views/pins/index.html.erb** you didn't put <% end %>

```
<span class='pin-<%=pin.id%>'>
  <%= link_to upvote_pin_path(pin), method: :put, remote: true do %>         
      <% if pin.votes.where(user_id: current_user.id).empty? %>
         <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= pin.votes.count %>
</span>
```

***app/views/pins/upvote.js.erb** jQuery selector was wrong and variable call was wrong too

```
$(".pin-<%=@pin.id%>").html('<%= @pin.votes.count.to_s %>');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Felix. Unfortunetaly the page still need to be refresh to show the updated value

Comment: Check if server responds with JS as it should. To do so, open Chrome developer tools, Network tab, click "Vote", and see the request which was sent. Response should be something like "$(".pin-12").html('21');". If it is not, check server logs for any errors.

Comment: I can't understand the errors from the logs unfortunetaly

Comment: Show errors from server log (where you run `rails s`) if there are any (first 5 lines after `Started PUT URL` would be enough)

Comment: Edit my answer with the errors from the server log returned

Comment: i get it to work through this adding this .to_s: $(".pin-<%=@pin.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript @pin.votes.count.to_s %>');   Thanks for your time and your Help Felix :) highly appreciated.

Comment: You can also remove escape_javascript because you don't have html rendered inside that ruby brackets.